# Anomalize r package error

Tags: r, anomaly-detection

I want to test Anomalize r package for an anomaly detection problem.
After checking [the github page](https://github.com/business-science/anomalize), I tried the example code they provided:

```
library(anomalize)

tidyverse_cran_downloads %>%
# Data Manipulation / Anomaly Detection
    time_decompose(count, method = "stl") %>%
    anomalize(remainder, method = "iqr") %>%
    time_recompose() %>%
# Anomaly Visualization
    plot_anomalies(time_recomposed = TRUE, ncol = 3, alpha_dots = 0.25) +
    labs(title = "Tidyverse Anomalies", subtitle = "STL + IQR Methods")
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
'arg' should be one of “second”, “minute”, “hour”, “day”, “week”, 
“month”, “year”
```

that I can't debug. Can anyone help?
If useful, I am using R version 3.4.3.

Cheers!

Comment: Have you tried running the code with the `tidyverse` package?

Comment: Yes, I had called the tidyverse package before running this chunk of code.

Comment: Odd, the code you posted worked for me. Which versions of `tidyverse` and `anomalize` are you running. You can check by executing `sessionInfo()`

Comment: It is weird indeed. I have tidyverse version 1.1.1 and anomalize version 0.1.1. What about you?

Comment: You may need to update `tidyverse` (I am running 1.2.1). To do this use `install.packages("tidyverse")`